# compiling with c89 and c99 does gcc 4.4.2 default to c99?

Tags: c, c99, c89

I am using gcc 4.4.2 on linux

I am just wondering does gcc automatically default to compiling with c99 as its the latest standard?

How can I specify if I want to compile with c89 or c99?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: The default is still gnu89 (i.e. c89 with GNU extensions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One reason not to use C99 by default is because this standard is not fully implemented in the compiler yet. However, I believe that you can set the default mode when compiling gcc, so if the choice of standards really matters for you, it's better always to pass the option.

The options are `-std=c99` and `-std=c89` respectively.

Comment: I normally compile with c89 as its more portable. But there are some features of c99 that I like. However, I can't use c99 standard as I need to compile on windows using VS, which only supports c89. Even the latest version of VS 2010 will not be implementing c89.

Comment: If I check [GCC C99status](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) I can't find any missing features that would affect most use cases. Could you give an example of a missing feature that could be blocking to use C99 compilation?

Comment: @RuudAlthuizen That answer was written in 2010. As of 2016, to the best of my knowledge, only expert aspects of floating-point are missing. “floating-point environment access in <fenv.h>” is marked as “Library feature, no compiler support required” but actually this **definitely** requires compiler support, which GCC does not provide.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I did notice the timestamp. I had added the comment because the question specifically mentions GCC 4.4.2, which doesn't matter for the support status.

Answer (score 9):

From the `gcc(1)` man page:

```
   -std=
       Determine the language standard.   This option is currently only
       supported when compiling C or C++.

....

       c99
       c9x
       iso9899:1999
       iso9899:199x
           ISO C99.  Note that this standard is not yet fully supported;
           see <http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html> for more
           information.  The names c9x and iso9899:199x are deprecated.

       gnu89
           GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is
           the default for C code.

       gnu99
       gnu9x
           GNU dialect of ISO C99.  When ISO C99 is fully implemented in
           GCC, this will become the default.  The name gnu9x is
           deprecated.
```